# Obtain z statistic from stats.wilcoxon

Tags: python-3.x, scipy, statistics

I'm running a wilcoxon test using `scipy.stats.wilcoxon()` and it returns a `W` and `p` value. However, I would also like to have the `z` statistic. Is there a way to calculate it from W and p?

Comment: I'm also looking for the same. I need to calculate the effect size. Have you found the solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

Started to create an account to give back to the community.

As I searched for this, apparently, I found this python package called pingouin
which computes wilcoxon signed rank test with effect size.

Here is the link:
[Pingouin](https://pingouin-stats.org/generated/pingouin.wilcoxon.html#:%7E:text=The%20Wilcoxon%20signed-rank%20test%20tests%20the%20null%20hypothesis,differences%20x%20-%20y%20is%20symmetric%20about%20zero.)

Hope this helps.